# How to pass value in JavaScript function(in <head>) to JSP form<body>?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to get a value from JavaScript function which is in  tag in jsp to form in

following is the code:

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
            total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
            }
        total = total / 1000.

    // **total** this is the value i need to get                
        }
```

this is the form in body,

```
<form:form  method="POST" action="${saveReceiptUrl}"></form:form>
```

I need to get that value in total variable to this form, how to do it??

Comment: Store in cookie and retrieve that cookie from JSP.

Answer (score 0):

@Sachith This is very simple, save the value in text/hidden box inside of form. So you can get that value in your servlet. You can set value using jquery like,

```
$("#text_box_id").val(total);
```

else if you need in JS,

```
document.getElementById('text_box_id').value = total
```

Hope this helps..